# FSA Omega BB30 spindle comes out of drive-side crank

Tags: crankset

I have a Cannondale CAAD Optimo Disc Tiagra that came with the FSA BB30 bottom bracket and the FSA Omega BB30 50/34 crank set pre-installed.

A couple of weeks ago I noticed that the chain started slightly touching the front dérailleur at one specific part of the revolution (right when I start applying torque pedalling down with my right foot). I took the crank set out and found that the spindle has slightly moved out from the drive-side crank (the one that it's supposed to be permanently attached to) and was a little wobbly. I applied a couple of hits with a hammer and brought it back in; assembled the crank set back to the frame and the problem was gone. Unfortunately, after riding a couple of miles the same problem re-appeared.

Has anyone had any experience with spindle sliding out of the drive-side crank and know how this could be solved? I tried removing the spindle out of the crank so that I could apply some glue and slide it back in but it doesn't seem that it can be removed, it simply slides out ~2.5mm and subsequently causes some lateral movement of the crank set.

Any help and opinions will be appreciated! I attach a photo of how it looks like. You can see how far the spindle should slide in normally.

[image: Spindle and drive-side crank]

Comment: Start by contacting FSA and see if its a known issue, and whether your warranty applies.  How old is it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the warranty doesn't apply to me as I am the 3rd owner of the bicycle. Though I have the original purchase receipt, it's nearly 2 years old. In any case, since this crankset has been through a good 1500mi with me and is rather heavy (it's actually one of the cheapest FSA options), I'll be upgrading it with SRAM Force 22.

Comment: I have the same problem with my FSA Omega crank on my Cannondale Caadx, this is the second one I have had with the same problem! The original one came loose after a slight clip of a curb, the other worked its way out with normal riding. Tried banging it back in but that does not work. In my opinion FSA cranks are rubbish and I will be replacing with a shimano.

Comment: Just had exactly the same problem with my 2015 FSA omega cranks that came on my Bianchi Vertigo. Think the verdict might be that cheap FSA stuff isn’t much good i’m afraid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've dealt with a bunch of these. There is no fix and you should stop riding it for safety. It's unclear what if anything causes it.

Getting an adhesive to fix it doesn't seem likely to me. You would need to get in and clean it, which isn't possible without doing major surgery on these. The contact surfaces will be mashed and it will be difficult to get the bearing contact face square. And most importantly, the interface is supposed to be a permanent press fit. The strength of this type of interface when it works as intended is much greater than what you could expect to get out of holding the same parts together in mangled form with epoxy.

Contact FSA or your dealer for warranty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nathan. I guess I will start looking for an upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

I'm inclined to think your crank is toast.

If there is nothing pulling the spindle into the drive crank with some force (like the non drive side crank is held on with a bolt), the spindle will always come loose. I do not think glue is going to be effective as that joint transmits all the torque from your left leg.

Comment: Thanks, Argenti. I'll be looking for a new crankset :)